# Get resource URI on s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

Currently, I construct URI by hand with string interpolation:

```
fmt.Sprintf("https://%s.%s.amazonaws.com/%s/%s", serviceId, region, namespace, filename)
```

which IMHO is bad as I pass them via parameters from env variables. I have access to aws.Session object which is correctly initialized with our s3 bucket.

Is there are a semantically correct way(probably with aws sdk API) to generate the same resource URI I do by *dummy* string builder?

Comment: amazonaws => amazonaws.com

Comment: @jarmod, good catch, sheriff

Comment: I'm not aware of any SDK methods (in the languages that I use; I don't use go) to construct S3 URIs. I simply use s3.region.amazonaws.com/bucket/key (path-style) or bucket.s3.region.amazonaws.com/key (virtual-hosted style). You can also substitute s3-region for s3.region.

Comment: Yes, `github.com/aws-sdk-go` does this for you automatically as you initialize your service and form your request (region set in service and Bucket set in request options). Are you asking about how to then retrieve the URI at that point, or does this information answer your question?

Comment: @Jonathan yes, I'm asking how to retrieve URI :)

Comment: I'm also struggling to get the URI from S4 bucket name and key. Can't find any API in AWS SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### From an example...

While `aws-sdk-go` does expose the `*http.Request` in a struct returned by `svc.GetObjectRequest`, the URL it returns is really more of a 'url format' until you run a method on the request like `Sign` or `Presign`.

A few `Presign` examples can be found [On This Page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/s3-example-presigned-urls.html). The Get example provides the following output:

> 2017/08/03 09:47:43 The URL is https://get-resource-uri-test.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/myKey?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIFJBK7YB3H7CTZIA%2F20170803%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20170803T144743Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=3c279aece1eda3c33b0711bb0e5a86e330e378f9052f1e73cdb0b9ca19de6209

*Note that I'm using 'get-resource-uri-test' as my bucket name since the one in the example was already in use*

---

#### Adjusted example

Since this isn't the kind of output you're looking for, I've adjusted the example to use `Sign`, which keeps things more clean since the auth info is put into headers/etc. instead of in the URL:

```
svc := s3.New(session.New(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String("us-west-2")}))
req, _ := svc.GetObjectRequest(&s3.GetObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String("get-resource-uri-test"),
    Key:    aws.String("myKey"),
})

// Instead of using Presign, which was provided in example
if err := req.Sign(); err != nil {
    log.Println("Failed to sign request", err)
}

log.Println("The URL is", req.HTTPRequest.URL)
```

> 2017/08/03 09:53:22 The URL is https://get-resource-uri-test.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/myKey

---

#### Considerations

While this suggestion does avoid actually making any calls to S3, I do have mixed feelings about it. In some respects, `aws-sdk-go` seems designed to somewhat eliminate the need for URL manipulation and instead generates it (mostly internally) as a consequence of what you're trying to accomplish.

So is it *really* necessary for us to create a whole S3 client to get a properly 'sanctioned/blessed' url from Amazon in Go? It seems a little overboard, but this is the only way I've found so far to receive a formatted URL from `aws-sdk-go`. If anyone else is able to come up with a more reasonable alternative, I'd encourage that person to post his/her solution as well.

I probably don't need to say this, but if this example is something you're planning to use at scale, I'd recommend creating a single s3 client (named `svc` in the example provided) and reusing its `GetObjectRequest` method to avoid creating a new client every time you need to determine a URL.